# Feed Dialog Garbling My Passed Referral Link Only When Post Image is Clicked?

Tags: facebook, url, dialog

I run a site that allows registered site members to refer people back to my site using their referral link

> (EX: http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=MaxP)

Recently I coded into my site an implementation of the "Direct URL Example" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) in order to enable my site members to post to their timeline a post which describes my site and includes their own referral link back to my site within the code.

Everything is working fine when a prospective site referral viewing the resulting post clicks upon the post link text (the get sent to a properly formatted referral link as planned - "http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=MaxP"

The problem I'm having is that in the same post if the prospective site referral clicks upon the **image** then the referral link get's garbled like this "http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=**nf**" which is a totally invalid referral link that has nothing to do with what link it should be sending them to ("http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=**MaxP**")

Why is facebook erroneously arbitrarily replacing the proper referrer "MaxP" with "NF" **only** when clicking upon the **image** of the post?  What does NF mean and why is it there?

Here is the URL that my code is passing to facebook (site url, app id, and name replaced to protect my privacy):

```
    https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=161070640444808&link=http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=MaxP&picture=http://www.mygreatsite.com/images/banners/9.jpg&name=mygreatsite.com%20Ultra-High%20Payout%20site&caption=Paying%20DAILY%20to%20virtual%20points&description=%20%20is%20an%20ultra-high%20paying%20get%20paid%20to%20%28site%29%20site&redirect_uri=http://www.mygreatsite.com/members/refer.php
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem I'm having is that in the same post if the prospective site referral clicks upon the image then the referral link get's garbled like this "http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=nf" which is a totally invalid referral link that has nothing to do with what link it should be sending them to ("http://www.mygreatsite.com/home?ref=MaxP")

`ref=nf` is a Facebook parameter for tracking where the link click came from/occurred (in this case nf = news feed).

I think Facebook just *overwrites* any pre-existing URL parameter of that very name by it’s own – so I’d suggest naming your own parameter something different, that does definitively *not* get used by Facebook, for example `myRef=MaxP`.

You will still get the `ref` param from Facebook, but it *should* result in an URL like `…/home?myRef=MaxP&ref=nf`, so that you’d still be able to read your own referral value from it as `myRef`. *(In theory; haven’t tested this myself yet – please let us know the result ;-))*

Comment: Oh, ok...  I get it.  Thank you very much.  Unfortunately that also means that I'm stuck with the problem as the site I'm referring to uses a leased script and my site has over 1000 members also using there referral links on other sites such as online discussion forums.  If I change the ref= parameter in the script then that would invalidate all those referral links in posts all over the web.

At least I have better insight on the cause of the issue - thank you.

Comment: I thought of a solution overnight.  Per4haps I should look into integrating a url shortener into my code instead of trying to use the raw referral url.